# $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \dim F_i>n(k-1) \Longrightarrow \bigcap_{i=1}^{k}F_i\neq \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a vector space of dimension $n$, and $F_1, F_2, ..., F_k$ be sub-spaces of $E$. Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \dim F_i > n(k-1) \Longrightarrow \bigcap_{i=1}^{k}F_i\neq \{0\}$$
Please I need some hints.

Comment: Let's say that we have $F_1,F_2$. Then $dimF_1 +dimF_2> n <=> dimF_1 +dimF_2 -dim(F_1\cap F_2)>n-dim(F_1\cap F_2) <=> dim(F_1+F_2)>n-dim(F_1 \cap F_2)<=>dim(F_1\cap F_2)> n-dim(F_1+F_2)>1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note by principle of inclusion-exclusion, $$\begin{align}\dim\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}F_i&=\dim F_{k}+\dim\bigcap_{i=1}^{k-1}F_{i}-\dim\left((\bigcap_{i=1}^{k-1}F_i)+F_{k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\dim F_i-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\dim\left((\bigcap_{i=1}^jF_i)+F_{j+1}\right)\\
&>n(k-1)-(k-1)\dim E=0\end{align}$$
which implies $\dim\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}F_i\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: I can't understand from where did you get the union in the 1st equality?

Comment: @Mohamez Denote $G_k=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}F_i$, then $G_k=G_{k-1}\cap F_k$ and $\dim G_k=\dim G_{k-1}+\dim F_k-\dim(G_{k-1}\cup F_k)$

Comment: @ShuchangZhang I think Mohamez might be asking for clarification about the use of $\cup$ here. (And if not, I'd like to ask :) ) Does it mean the set-union or does it mean the span of the $F_k$?

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks. That means the space which is union of two subspaces. I changed the sign to +, which seems to be more common.